# What datatype is this? is it wordpress specific?

Tags: php, json, data-structures

Hey can anyone tell me what datatype this is? it wont parse as i've stripped out sensitive data. Am I correct in thinking its json?

> a:7:{s:12:"competitions";a:893:{i:1;s:10:"Ersie";i:5;s:19:"General
>
> News"1510126584;s:0:"";i:1019;s:0:"";i:8284;s:0:"";i:191016;s:0:"";i:284;s:0:"";i:91019;s:0:"";i:81863;s:0:"";i:1563;s:0:"";i:710138;s:0:"";i:101333;s:0:"";i:33430;s:0:"";i:10224;s:0:"";i:10430;s:0:"";i:13430;s:0:"";i:375;s:0:"";i:72107;s:0:"";i:11372;s:0:"";i:181372;s:0:"";i:1885;s:0:"";i:107155;s:0:"";i:10284;s:0:"";i:8206;s:0:"";i:8101316;s:0:"";i:1913;s:0:"";i:206;s:0:"";i:772138;s:0:"";i:72284;s:0:"";i:1672155;s:0:"";i:7101663;s:0:"";i:891013;s:0:"";i:101843;s:0:"";i:1107;s:0:"";i:1072;s:0:"";i:830;s:0:"";i:7284;s:0:"";i:8101333;s:0:"";i:13372;s:0:"";i:1570;s:0:"";i:2543;s:0:"";i:91316;s:0:"";i:385;s:0:"";i:8385;s:0:"";i:2843;s:0:"";i:695;s:0:"";i:1970;s:0:"";i:1661;s:0:"";i:18206;s:0:"";i:33155;s:0:"";i:787;s:0:"";i:8117;s:0:"";i:1943;s:0:"";i:3043;s:0:"";i:872239;s:0:"";i:872155;s:0:"";i:910104;s:0:"";i:8125;s:0:"";i:239;s:0:"";i:8428;s:0:"";i:1382;s:0:"";i:87293;s:0:"";i:95385;s:0:"";i:11672;s:0:"";i:92572;s:0:"";i:828;s:0:"";i:8239;s:0:"";i:640;s:0:"";i:87155241;s:0:"";i:26155241;s:0:"";i:87158241;s:0:"";i:69158241;s:0:"";i:82543;s:0:"";i:193372;s:0:"";i:90163241;s:0:"";i:163372;s:0:"";i:1016107;s:0:"";i:86372;s:0:"";i:87163241;s:0:"";i:155162241;s:0:"";i:713121;s:0:"";i:2690241;s:0:"";i:895430;s:0:"";i:-403549467;s:0:"";i:2060490689;s:0:"";i:7181924;s:0:"";i:157158241;s:0:"";i:87295;s:0:"";i:71672430;s:0:"";i:1372430;s:0:"";i:9430;s:0:"";i:897;s:0:"";i:242;s:0:"";i:87162241;s:0:"";i:161863;s:0:"";i:1824107;s:0:"";i:26165241;s:0:"";i:7891316;s:0:"";i:81670;s:0:"";i:43107;s:0:"";i:710121;s:0:"";i:172283;s:0:"";i:8790241;s:0:"";i:253372;s:0:"";i:71863;s:0:"";i:26157241;s:0:"";i:8393;s:0:"";i:91824;s:0:"";i:826;s:0:"";i:63640;s:0:"";i:26163241;s:0:"";i:13121;s:0:"";i:82574;s:0:"";i:165241;s:0:"";i:87157241;s:0:"";i:2687241;s:0:"";i:26162241;s:0:"";i:199;s:0:"";i:18910;s:0:"";i:162165241;s:0:"";i:751430;s:0:"";i:16125;s:0:"";i:81893;s:0:"";i:79101316;s:0:"";i:81693;s:0:"";i:8913119;s:0:"";i:7818;s:0:"";i:72223;s:0:"";i:781072;s:0:"";i:972107;s:0:"";i:26241;s:0:"";i:90158241;s:0:"";i:87071;s:0:"";i:816125;s:0:"";i:72155430;s:0:"";i:72109;s:0:"";i:8106;s:0:"";i:181;s:0:"";i:8126;s:0:"";i:897293;s:0:"";i:187;s:0:"";i:101318;s:0:"";i:7166372;s:0:"";i:13216;s:0:"";i:101367;s:0:"";i:91149;s:0:"";i:781633;s:0:"";i:7101363;s:0:"";i:872430;s:0:"";i:1657;s:0:"";i:215;s:0:"";i:1025;s:0:"";i:7136372;s:0:"";i:1314;s:0:"";i:101319;s:0:"";i:1372344;s:0:"";i:1372573;s:0:"";i:1672430;s:0:"";i:872109;s:0:"";i:972430;s:0:"";i:193372430;s:0:"";i:13171;s:0:"";i:172430;s:0:"";i:6372430;s:0:"";i:772430;s:0:"";i:1372155430;s:0:"";i:71372;s:0:"";i:887;s:0:"";i:78933344;s:0:"";i:8131672;s:0:"";i:131672;s:0:"";i:365;s:0:"";i:91172;s:0:"";i:772155;s:0:"";i:972155;s:0:"";i:137072;s:0:"";i:729;s:0:"";i:781672;s:0:"";i:891172;s:0:"";i:924;s:0:"";i:796372;s:0:"";i:94372;s:0:"";i:284385;s:0:"";i:72344;s:0:"";i:71372121;s:0:"";i:78972;s:0:"";i:136372;s:0:"";i:713211;s:0:"";i:17972;s:0:"";i:101872;s:0:"";i:17872;s:0:"";i:84370;s:0:"";i:71633;s:0:"";i:172107;s:0:"";i:833732;s:0:"";i:18101318;s:0:"";i:816155;s:0:"";i:83343;s:0:"";i:43155;s:0:"";i:438;s:0:"";i:104363;s:0:"";i:961;s:0:"";i:843732;s:0:"";i:78107;s:0:"";i:13344;s:0:"";i:72393;s:0:"";i:83363;s:0:"";i:113121;s:0:"";i:863121;s:0:"";i:8131643;s:0:"";i:518;s:0:"";i:1789;s:0:"";i:61107;s:0:"";i:891619;s:0:"";i:43214;s:0:"";i:63121;s:0:"";i:7136430;s:0:"";i:81865;s:0:"";i:728430;s:0:"";s:11:"10245074125";s:0:"";i:63162;s:0:"";i:393;s:0:"";i:89732;s:0:"";i:2633430;s:0:"";i:157283430;s:0:"";}s:8:"lastpost";i:1281041491;s:7:"default";s:19:"General
>
> News";s:11:"autopublish";s:2:"on";s:5:"draft";N;s:6:"poster";s:1:"1";s:6:"suffix";s:0:"";}

Answer (score 6):

This is a serialized PHP array.  Essentially, it's just a string that represents a PHP array (the `a` at the beginning marks it as an array).

You can get the PHP array back out of it by passing the string to the PHP function `unserialize()`.

Answer (score 1):

That is serialized data - not Wordpress specific.

Take a look into [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php), [`unserialize()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) and [OOP serialization](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php): [`__sleep()`/`__wakeUp()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.sleep).